# Tailwindcss + EJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ejs

El tailwindcss solo me lee el archivo principal, los demas archivos que puedan tener clases tailwind en otras carpeta no los lee, ya modifique el **tailwindcss.config.js**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Hay como se ve tengo el tailwindcss bien en esa pagina***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Luego de que clicko el boton me lleva a otra ruta donde renderizo toda la info, sin embargo no me lee el css, y la ruta esta correcta***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No tengo experiencia con ejs pero ¿puede que sea ../public en lugar de ./public desde la vista? Si tocas inspeccionar en la pestaña network puedes ver efectivamente si está cargando el recurso css o no.

Comment: Tenias razon la ruta estaba mal pero aun asi todavia no descarga ni siquiera el css :( , probe colocando el res.status(200) al controlador pensando que seria eso pero no creo que sacare esas pieza y la probare aparte haber  que es lo que pasa, Gracias :)

Comment: Me alegra haber sido de ayuda. ¿el GET en la consola que muestras en la segunda captura ahora te da 200 para el css?

Comment: Creo que ya he encontrado lo que esta mal, en la consola como me dijiste me coloque a mirar y resulta ser que tengo como 300 errores de (samesite-cookies), cuando coloco la vista en la carpeta /public funciona perfectamente sin embargo cuando esta afuera de ella no ... creo que es algo de las cookies .

Comment: me sigue dando (404) cuando esta fuera de la carpeta /public, si la dejo adentro me aparece perfectamente (200)